# Script crashing every other time I initialize it when trying to render text

Tags: python, text, pygame, crash, render

So I'm trying to teach myself Python, and as a project I'm trying to create the game Connect 4 using pygame. I've implemented a debugging function that displays the coordinates of all tiles, but when I activate it (setting the variable 'debug' to '1', every other time I try to initialize the script, it just turns black and crashes. The other 50% of the times, it works fine. It does not happen when I disable the text rendering. However, I have no idea why this happens, and am not getting any error reports in my console.

I'm writing in Spyder via the Anaconda3 distribution, in Python 3.7, using Pygame 2.0.1.

This is the code. The problematic lines seem to be 41-43 and perhaps 75-79, but I have no idea what may be wrong. Does anybody know what might be the problem? It also happens with different fonts.

```
import sys
import pygame

# ==== Settings ====

scalingFactor = 2 #Must be an integer

displayWidth = 320 * scalingFactor
displayHeight = 375 * scalingFactor
displaySize = [displayWidth, displayHeight]

Black = (0, 0, 0)
White = (255, 255, 255)
Grey = (255, 255, 255)
Red = (255, 20, 20)
Blue = (80, 80, 255)

player1 = Red
player2 = Blue
turnColor = player1 #Starting color

frameBackgroundColor = White
frameLatticeColor = Black
frameMargin = 5 * scalingFactor
gridWidth = 40 * scalingFactor
gridHeight = 40 * scalingFactor
columns = 7
rows = 6

fontColor = Black

debug = 1

# ==== Code ====

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(displaySize)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.display.set_caption('Connect Four')

if debug == 1: #Line 43 starts here
    #This somehow makes the script unstable and won't allow it to run every other time I try to initialize it.
    font = pygame.font.Font(None, 24)

running = True

grid = []
for row in range(rows):
    grid.append([])
    for column in range(columns):
        grid[row].append(0)

def drawGrid():
    for row in range(rows):
        for column in range(columns):
            color = White
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, 
                             color,
                             [(frameMargin + gridWidth) * column + frameMargin,
                              (frameMargin + gridHeight) * row + frameMargin,
                              gridWidth, gridHeight])
            
            if grid[row][column] == 1:
                pygame.draw.circle(screen, 
                                   player1, 
                                   [(frameMargin + gridWidth) * column + frameMargin + gridWidth // 2, 
                                    (frameMargin + gridHeight) * row + frameMargin + gridHeight // 2], 
                                    gridWidth // 2 - 5)
            if grid[row][column] == 2:
                pygame.draw.circle(screen, 
                                   player2, 
                                   [(frameMargin + gridWidth) * column + frameMargin + gridWidth // 2, 
                                    (frameMargin + gridHeight) * row + frameMargin + gridHeight // 2], 
                                    gridWidth // 2 - 5)
            if debug == 1: #Line 75 starts here
                textString = str(row) + "," + str(column)
                textRender = font.render(textString, True, fontColor)
                screen.blit(textRender,((frameMargin + gridWidth) * column + frameMargin + 8, 
                                        (frameMargin + gridHeight) * row + frameMargin + 8))

def validTile_check(validTile, pos, column, row):
    
    # Checks if registered click is on tile or on frame lattice
    if pos[0] % (gridWidth + frameMargin) <= frameMargin or pos[1] % (gridWidth + frameMargin) <= frameMargin:
        print("Click registered on", pos, ". Not on tile.")
    # Checks if registered click is within grid
    elif row > rows - 1 or column > columns - 1:
        print("Click registered on", pos, ". With grid coordinates:", row, column, ". Not a tile.")
        validTile = 0
    # Checks if registered click is on bottom tile
    elif grid[row][column] == 0 and row == rows - 1:
        validTile = 1
    # Checks if registered click is on tile with placed piece in tile below
    elif grid[row][column] == 0 and grid[row + 1][column] > 0:
        validTile = 1
    else: 
        validTile = 0
        
    return validTile

def winCheck(winCondition, grid, pos, column, row):
    
    winCondition = 0
    chain = 1     
    
    for n in range(1, 3):
        if chain == 4:
            winCondition = 1
            break
        if row + n < rows:
            if grid[row][column] == grid[row + n][column]:
                chain += 1
            else:
                break

    return winCondition

while running:
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            column = pos[0] // (gridWidth + frameMargin)
            row = pos[1] // (gridHeight + frameMargin)
            validTile = 0
            winCondition = 0
            
            validTile = validTile_check(validTile, pos, column, row)
            
            if validTile == 0:
                print("Click registered on", pos, ". With grid coordinates:", row, column, ". Not a valid tile.")
            # Marks tile if clicked tile was unmarked.
            elif grid[row][column] == 0:
                if turnColor == player1:
                    grid[row][column] = 1
                    turnColor = player2
                elif turnColor == player2:
                    grid[row][column] = 2
                    turnColor = player1
                print("Click registered on", pos, ". With grid coordinates:", row, column, ". Tile marked.")
            # Unmarks tile if clicked tile was marked.
            elif grid[row][column] > 0:
                grid[row][column] = 0
                print("Click registered on", pos, ". With grid coordinates:", row, column, ". Tile unmarked.")
                
            winCheck(winCondition, grid, pos, column, row)
            
            if winCondition == 1:
                print("Winner!")
        
    screen.fill(Black)
    drawGrid()
    pygame.display.update()
    
    clock.tick(60)
    

pygame.quit()
```

The console looks like this:

```
   In [2]: runfile('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Connect4/Game/gameFrame.py', wdir='C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Connect4/Game')
    
   In [1]: runfile('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Connect4/Game/gameFrame.py', wdir='C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Connect4/Game')
    pygame 2.0.1 (SDL 2.0.14, Python 3.7.4)
    Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
    
   In [2]: runfile('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Connect4/Game/gameFrame.py', wdir='C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Connect4/Game')
    pygame 2.0.1 (SDL 2.0.14, Python 3.7.4)
    Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
    
   In [1]:
    
   In [2]: runfile('C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Connect4/Game/gameFrame.py', wdir='C:/Users/Admin/Documents/Connect4/Game')
```

When it shows 'Hello from the pygame community.' it works, and when it shows nothing, or just the 'runfile()' line, it crashes.

Comment: How is it crashing? Is an exception being raised? If so, please include the full error message and traceback. Which lines are lines 41-43 and 75-79?

Comment: When I run the script, it either works, or the window just stays black for a few seconds and exits. No error message, no nothing. I'll add line numbers to the original post and include an annotated excerpt of the console log.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. What is your OS?

Comment: Windows 10 Home 64 bit. Some more specs: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-9600K, 16GB RAM.

Comment: I recommend to use [`pygame.font.SysFont`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.SysFont) instead of [`pygame.font.Font`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font) : `font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 24)`

Comment: That was what I was initially using, but that made the issue even worse. Here is a screenshot of what it looks like when it crashes: [link](https://i.imgur.com/f4WeKCb.png)

Comment: Does anything change if you use a valid font name? e.g.  `pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 24)`

Comment: No, unfortunately not.

Comment: This is very strange, `pygame.font.SysFont (None, 24)` should always work. It seems to be related to your system in some way.

Comment: I just tried running the code in Jupyter Notebook, and the same thing happens. Would you know any way I could possible try and find what the source of this issue is? I wouldn't even know where to start.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot reproduce the issue. However, I am using Python 3.9.1

Comment: I also could not reproduce the issue. I am using Python 3.9.5. I would probably try downloading a newer version of Python and testing to see if that may be where the issue lies. Cool program though, I thought it was fun

Answer (score 1):

I still don't exactly know what was wrong, but it seems that it was not the code. I updated my Python version to 3.9.5, and downloaded a new version of the IDE I was using, via another downloader instead of Anaconda3. Any of these things may have solved it, but it is no longer crashing!